# ReactJS - Data Changing/Refreshing

Tags: api, reactjs

I'm new to React, I think the basics have sunk in but I'm stuck on something.  We're going to re-build one of our old systems and I'd like to do it in React.

Our system is an internal CRM, each set of client data is about a Mb in size, so efficiency is one of our priorities. The logic is done on a separate API, used by lots of different systems, so 99% of this front end is CRUD only.

(I hope I'm explaining this Ok!)

So onto my question. If I make a small change to a part of the client data, say I add an 'Audit' to the client... there is a chance that LOTS of other data changes. Complex enough that I don't want to replicate the logic both front end & API side.

Would I need to have the API return the full Mb of data, to have the root level app re-render all it's components? Or is there a more efficient way of doing it? Should I be setting up each component to periodically ping the API to check for changes individually?

I'm just a little bit lost where to start tackling the idea of it. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first - React Components rerender when any props or state field was changed.

If you change smth on the client-side and changes should affect server-side which important for user, then you do should updated your app view. To make it more smooth you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` method of Component's lifecycle to prevent unnecessary re-renders.

If server-side updates are not important for user (some meta data...), then you may not update the state of you application, by that you prevent re-renders.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...So if server-side change is important to user.  I should download the full 1MB client data file into my state?  Even if only 1 value has changed? (But that 1 value, could be 10 values, 50 values, etc. It depends.)

Comment: Could you load only a chunk of those data? E.g. use paging or infinite scroll.

Comment: Yeah that is possible.  Alright, thanks Ivan I appreciate it :)